# Can we replace "firefighting team" with "it"?

Tags: grammar

Does it make sense to replace firefighting team with it if the word firefighting team was never mentioned? I am not a native English speaker, but it sounds odd to say it to refer to firefighting team.

> "I remember getting a call from the fire department commander, telling
>   me that they were not sure they were gonna be able to contain the
>   fire, and I said, 'We've had such terrible loss of life, maybe the
>   smartest thing to do is **pull it**.' And they made that decision to
>   pull and then we watched the building collapse." Larry Silverstein

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It" can replace "team" (and consequently, "firefighting team") in other contexts.

However, in this context, "pull" seems to refer to "pulling" the entire firefighting **action / effort**.